# Error: Table or view does not exist in PL SQL package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scripting

I have a package called 'S_PKG' in schema 'A'. I want to migrate it into schema B. What I did was I copied the code and executed in B schema. Then I wanted to execute the following pl sql script in which the 'S_PKG' is used in schema B.

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD - HH:MI:SS AM') date_time
from dual
/
insert into zzz_ccc
select zzz_ccc_seq.nextval,to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD - HH:MI:SS AM'),
'Start S Load tab',8,user,(select * from global_name)
from dual
/
commit
/
insert into zzz
select zzz_seq.nextval,to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD - HH:MI:SS AM'),
'Start S Load tab',
(select trim(ruser)||' '||trim(rdbase)
from zzz_ccc where ss = 8
and rr = (select max(rr) from zzz_ccc where ss = 8)),
null,null,null,null,null,null,
(select max(rr) from zzz_ccc where ss = 8)
from dual 
/
commit
/
DECLARE
  PV_PRD_ID VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  PV_PRD_ID := '3';
  B.S_PKG.PR_MAIN (PV_PRD_ID);
  COMMIT; 
END; 
/
commit
/
insert into tab_counts(created_dtm,
ora_database,ora_user,ora_table,cc,flg,
subj)
select sysdate,'ccenter','aim10_ccenter','s_package_run - rows',
no_of_rows,1,
'S Load Tab Run'
from s_package_run
where to_char(st_date,'YYYYMM-DD') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM-DD')
and package_name = 'LOAD_TAB'
/
commit
/
insert into tab_counts(created_dtm,
ora_database,ora_user,ora_table,cc,flg,
subj)
select sysdate,'ccenter','aim10_ccenter','s_package_run - dur_min',
dur_min,2,
'S Load Tab Run'
from s_package_run
where to_char(st_date,'YYYYMM-DD') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM-DD')
and package_name = 'LOAD_TAB'
/
insert into hrc_chk_mar14_24_1
select sysdate, 'B', 'COUNT 6   ', 's_load_tab',
null,null,null,null
from dual t1
/
insert into zzz
select zzz_seq.nextval,to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD - HH:MI:SS AM'),
'End S Load tab',
(select trim(ruser)||' '||trim(rdbase)
from zzz_ccc where ss = 8
and rr = (select max(rr) from zzz_ccc where ss = 8)),
null,null,
null,null,null,null,
(select max(rr) from zzz_ccc where ss = 8)
from dual 
/
commit
/
```

Then I got the following error.

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "B.S_PKG", line 109
ORA-06512: at "B.S_PKG", line 35
ORA-06512: at line 5**

Then I searched for the package. But I could not find the exact table which gives me the error. Here is my package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY B.S_PKG is


PROCEDURE PR_Main(kseq number) IS
sql_stmnt varchar2(5000);
begin

select s_pkg_seq.nextval into dd from dual;

pkg_st_date := sysdate;

sql_stmnt:='truncate table s_msgs';

execute immediate sql_stmnt;


begin
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = kseq and
flg = 'as' order by pkg_ord)
loop
   if substr(c_rec.run_sql,1,1) != '-' then
   pkg_name :=  c_rec.run_sql;
   PR_Msgs('*** '||c_rec.run_sql||' Started...', pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   else
   PR_Msgs(c_rec.run_sql, pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   end if;
   insert into s_test_3
   values(sysdate,c_rec.run_sql,c_rec.pkg_seq,c_rec.pkg_ord,c_rec.prc_seq);
end loop;
end;


PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(1,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(2,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(3,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(4,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(5,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(6,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(7,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(8,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(9,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(10,kseq);

PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(11,kseq);


begin
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = kseq and
flg = 'ae' order by pkg_ord)
loop
   if substr(c_rec.run_sql,1,1) != '-' then
   PR_Msgs('*** '||c_rec.run_sql||' End OK...', pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   else
   PR_Msgs(c_rec.run_sql, pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   end if;
   insert into s_test_3
   values(sysdate,c_rec.run_sql,c_rec.pkg_seq,c_rec.pkg_ord,c_rec.prc_seq);
end loop;
end;

sql_stmnt:='insert into s_msgs_his select * from s_msgs where msg_ord > 0';

execute immediate sql_stmnt;

pkg_en_date := sysdate;

insert into s_package_run values (pkg_st_date,pkg_en_date,floor((pkg_en_date-pkg_st_date)*24*60),
(pkg_en_date-pkg_st_date)*24*60*60 - floor((pkg_en_date-pkg_st_date)*24*60)*60,gv_count,
pkg_name,null,dd);


end;

-- ==============================================================================================
-- ==============================================================================================

PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_PRODUCT3(pseq number, tseq number) is
sql_stmnt VARCHAR2(5000);
begin

prc_st_date := sysdate;

begin
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = tseq and
prc_seq = pseq and flg = 'bs' order by pkg_ord)
loop
   prc_name :=  c_rec.run_sql;
   PR_Msgs(c_rec.run_sql||' Started...', pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   insert into s_test_3
   values(sysdate,c_rec.run_sql,c_rec.pkg_seq,c_rec.pkg_ord,c_rec.prc_seq);
end loop;
end;

begin
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = tseq and
prc_seq = pseq and flg = 'aa' order by pkg_ord)

loop
     sql_stmnt := c_rec.run_sql;
     execute immediate sql_stmnt;
     insert into s_test_3
     values(sysdate,c_rec.run_sql,c_rec.pkg_seq,c_rec.pkg_ord,c_rec.prc_seq);
end loop;
end;

begin
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = tseq and
prc_seq = pseq and flg = 'be' order by pkg_ord)
loop
   if substr(c_rec.run_sql,1,1) != '-' then
   PR_Msgs(c_rec.run_sql||' End OK...', pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   else
   PR_Msgs(c_rec.run_sql, pkg_name||'.'||'pr_main');
   end if;
   insert into s_test_3
   values(sysdate,c_rec.run_sql,c_rec.pkg_seq,c_rec.pkg_ord,c_rec.prc_seq);
end loop;
end;


select cc into gv_count
from cr2_test_2;

prc_en_date := sysdate;

insert into s_procedure_run values (prc_st_date,prc_en_date,floor((prc_en_date-prc_st_date)*24*60),
(prc_en_date-prc_st_date)*24*60*60 - floor((prc_en_date-prc_st_date)*24*60)*60,gv_count,
prc_name,pkg_name,dd);

end;

-- ==============================================================================================
-- ==============================================================================================

PROCEDURE PR_Msgs(pv_msg varchar2, pv_point varchar2) as
cc number(5);
Begin


select s_pkg2_seq.nextval into cc from dual;

insert into s_msgs values (sysdate, pv_msg, pv_point, user, '','',cc);
commit;

End;

-- ==============================================================================================
-- ==============================================================================================


END S_PKG;
/
```

Can anyone help me to find the error as I am new to PL SQL packages?

Comment: Shouldn't you declare `A` in `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY A.S_PKG`?

Comment: Then I get the insufficient privilege error. Is it wrong the way I create the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if you compiled the package when connected as user B and it was successful, then the only "unknown" information at that time is this:

```
sql_stmnt:='truncate table s_msgs';
```

i.e. the table you're truncating using dynamic SQL. `sql_stmnt`'s value is a string, compiler doesn't check what's in there. But, when you actually *execute* it, then it finds out that there's no table `s_msgs` in user B's schema.

The same goes for

```
sql_stmnt:='insert into s_msgs_his select * from s_msgs where msg_ord > 0';
```

and table `s_msgs_his`.

As you moved everything from A to B, I guess that you should do the same with those tables. Do that and then try to run your code again.

**[EDIT]**

This is line 109:

```
for c_rec in (select * from s_test_1 where pkg_seq = tseq and
prc_seq = pseq and flg = 'aa' order by pkg_ord)

loop
     sql_stmnt := c_rec.run_sql;
     execute immediate sql_stmnt;         --> line 109
```

Check what's written in `S_TEST_1`.  Looks like some statement that is supposed to be executed dynamically, but - the table involved into it doesn't exist in schema B (or that user doesn't have privileges to use it).

Comment: I created the same 2 tables in B schema. But the problem is still there

Comment: Aha. I should have read the question more carefully. I edited my answer, have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This code is not written by me. According to my understand 'c_rec.run_sql' is a procedure. 's_test_1' contains sql statements such as 'drop table x' etc. But some tables(eg: x) are not in B schema. Is it the problem or when I execute the package should these tables created?

Comment: Whatever command is stored in `c_rec.run_sql` is causing the error at runtime. You need to check what that failing command is.

Comment: RMD, you're closer now. C_REC.RUN_SQL is not a procedure. C_REC is a cursor variable, while RUN_SQL is a column from the S_TEST_1 table, but yes - you got the point, I think. In order to find out the culprit, put this as the first statement within the loop:   `dbms_output.put_line('executing ' || c_rec.run_sql);` as it'll show the statement. If it fails, you'll be able to see it and, hopefully, fix it.